# Функция для удаления элементов со списка

Tags: c++

Вот в этом коде есть функция ElAdd, которая добавляет элементы в свисок. Помогите мне на основе данного кода написать функцию ElDel - для удаления элементов со списка.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct element {
    string data;
    element *adress;
};

class List {
  private:
    element * StartAdress, *FinishAdress;

  public:
    List() {
        StartAdress = NULL;
        FinishAdress = NULL;
    } void ElAdd(string a) {
        element *e;
        e = new element;
        e->data = a;
        e->adress = StartAdress;
        StartAdress = e;
    }

    void print() {
        if (StartAdress == NULL) {
            cout << "List is Emptyn";
            return;
        }

        element *e;
        for (e = StartAdress; e != NULL; e = e->adress)
            cout << e->data << " " << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    string x, y, z, a, b;
    getline(cin, x);
    getline(cin, y);
    getline(cin, z);
    getline(cin, a);
    getline(cin, b);

    cout << "--------------------------" << endl;

    List L;
    L.ElAdd(x);
    L.ElAdd(y);
    L.ElAdd(z);
    L.ElAdd(a);
    L.ElAdd(b);

    L.print();

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как создавали, так и удаляем. Чего здесь непонятного ?

```
if (StartAdress) {
   element *e = StartAdress->adress;
   delete StartAdress;
   StartAdress = e;
}
```

Comment: спасибо! Сработало!
А как вот сделать, чтобы по нажатию на "D" удалять поочередно элементы ( x, y, z, a, b). Я сам попытался вот так:
while (v=='d') L.ElDel();
Но только не знаю что писать в скобках L.ElDel() чтобы он поочередно удалял их. Подскажешь?